# Adding onto a java.util.regex.Pattern or Merging Them

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching, filenames

I'm holding filename format data in a `Pattern` object. For example: `_\\d+x\\d+\\.png`. In my setup, this would denote icons of different sizes (e.g. `icon_16x16.png`, `icon_48x48.png` and so on).

I have a method that compares an actual filename with the given pattern; however, a base name must also be provided (in my example, this would be "icon"):

```
public boolean matches(String filename, String baseName) {
    if (!IOCase.SYSTEM.checkStartsWith(filename, baseName)) {
        return false;
    }

    return format.matcher(filename.replaceFirst(baseName, "")).matches();
}
```

What I'm doing here is first checking if `filename` starts with the base name. If so, the base name is stripped from the filename string so that it can be compared with the `Pattern` object (`format`).

I know I could do `return filename.matches(Pattern.quote(baseName) + format.pattern())`, but I'm wondering if there's a better, hopefully more programmatic way of doing this.

**To be precise, I want to know if it's possible to add onto a** `java.util.regex.Pattern` **or merge two of them without dealing with their underlying string representations.**

Comment: Your approach is 100% programmatic. What is your question?

Comment: You already have 2 programmatic ways.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to include the most important part of the question. Edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot modify a compiled `Pattern`.  You could create a new `Pattern` by combining the regex strings and calling `Pattern.compile()` again.

Answer (score 1):

Find below a sample code using pattern/matcher/group without any string manipulation:

If prefix is word chars only

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)(_\\d+x\\d+\\.png)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("icon1_16x16.png");
    String baseName = "icon";
            //If match found, m.group(1) returns the prefix of `_..x..png`
    if(m.find() && baseName.equals(m.group(1))){
         System.out.println("Match Found");
    }else{
       System.out.println("Match Not Found");
    }
```

If prefix can be any character, then use regex as `(.+)(_\\d+x\\d+\\.png)`